# XSD File Build Action

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xsd

I have to embed XSD file into my .Net project as a resource. I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community edition. As I read,  many resources says I can change my files build action as `Resource` from the file properties.

But in my IDE I can't see the any option regarding to that. Do I need to activate that option or what I have missed?

This is how its look like when I select file properties.

[image]

These are the all the options it provide and there is no any `Advanced` section in that which have to contain `Build Action` option as resources says. But that option is enabled in C# files.

[image]

How I can enable to select build option for XSD file in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: I add a xsd file in `Visual Studio Enterprise 2019`. And I can see Build Action in the property.

Comment: Here I'm using community edition. But I don't think that they have not enabled that option is community edition. I think its sort of a issue with my IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Previously I was adding file into solution. But I have to add file into project instead of solution to have that option.